# How do you select audio input device in core audio?

Tags: audio, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I am writing a program that needs to deal with multiple audio inputs.

I am currently using AudioQueues to get the input, but this is only from the default input device.

Is there any way to either:

- Select which input device the AudioQueues use.
- Change the default input device.

I know that I can use kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices in Core-Audio to get a list of output devices, is there a similar one I can use for input devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices` is used for both output and input devices. Devices can have both input and output channels, or can have only input or output channels.

Most of the AudioDevice... functions take a Boolean isInput parameter so that you ca query the input side of the device.

Comment: Thanks! I just found kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice which should do the job nicely.

Unfortunately the AudioDevice functions are deprecated so I have to use AudioObjectGetPropertyData instead, but that doesn't have a boolean for isInput. Any idea how to distinguish from input and output devices using this method?

Comment: Take a look at [Tech Note TN2223](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2010/tn2223.html) "Moving Off Deprecated HAL APIs". I think you'd set `AudioObjectPropertyScope` to select input or output.

Comment: To distinguish between input and output , get the `AudioStreamID(selector:kAudioDevicePropertyStreams)` from `AudioStreamID` get channel direction selector:`kAudioStreamPropertyDirection`. The direction 0 indicates output channel and 1 indicates input channel.

Comment: The tech note mentioned by @lucius [has moved here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2223/_index.html)

Answer (score 3):

I banged my head against how to do this for a while, and finally figured it out:

```
BOOL isMic = NO;
BOOL isSpeaker = NO;

AudioDeviceID device        = audioDevices[i];

// Determine direction of the device by asking for the number of input or 
// output streams.
propertyAddress.mSelector   = kAudioDevicePropertyStreams;
propertyAddress.mScope      = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput;

UInt32 dataSize             = 0;
OSStatus status             = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(device, 
                                                             &propertyAddress, 
                                                             0, 
                                                             NULL, 
                                                             &dataSize);        
UInt32 streamCount          = dataSize / sizeof(AudioStreamID);

if (streamCount > 0) 
{
    isMic = YES;
}

propertyAddress.mScope  = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;      
dataSize                = 0;
status                  = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(device, 
                                                         &propertyAddress, 
                                                         0, 
                                                         NULL,  
                                                         &dataSize);        
streamCount             = dataSize / sizeof(AudioStreamID);

if (streamCount > 0) 
{
    isSpeaker = YES;
}
```

As you can see, the key part is to use the ScopeInput/ScopeOutput parameter values.